# Set default unix datetime in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to insert a default Unix date time in database table. But i can't able to insert this. Please help me to set the default Unix date time.Am new for Oracle.

Comment: Why do you want to store a Unix date instead of a proper database `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type?

Comment: Some one told. It's very useful to search the data quickly. That's why i need this.Because my table have more than crore data.

Comment: @user1804985 - Declaring the field as a `NUMBER` and inserting the Unix timestamp doesn't do anything to allow you to search the data quickly.  It's at least as easy to search data stored in a proper `DATE` column particularly since that's what all of Oracles date/ time functions can handle.

Comment: Did this question just become a duplicate when you asked this very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656520/create-trigger-for-auto-incerment-id-and-default-unix-datetime ?  Or is there a difference that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SYSDATE` returns the current day and time as an Oracle `DATE` (an Oracle `DATE` always contains both a day and a time component to the second).

`SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the current day and time as an Oracle `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` which includes both fractional seconds and a time zone.

If you want to insert a `NUMBER` that represents the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 (which I'm assuming is what you mean by "Unix date time format", that would be `(SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24`.

Comment: Yes, You are right. I want to insert this Unix value to my date field automatically when i insert a data.

Comment: @user1804985 - If the column is defined as a `DATE`, you cannot insert a numeric value.  If you want to store a numeric value, the column must be declared as a `NUMBER`.

Comment: I declare the datatype for that column name is number.

Comment: @user1804985 - Then, as I said, you can insert the result of `(SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24` into the `NUMBER` column.

Comment: K thank you. But it inserted automatically when i insert a record without date field.

Comment: @user1804985 - Sorry, I'm not sure what you are saying.  Do you have a problem?  If so, please explain exactly what the problem is.  What behavior are you seeing?  What behavior do you want?  What is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `SYSTIMESTAMP` e.g. below?

```
  INSERT INT TABLE(A, B, DATETIMECOL) 
  VALUES ('a', 'b', SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

This will insert current time stamp of the server in the database.

Comment: I need like as getdate() function in sql.

Comment: What do you mean? Create a function with query as: `SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL`, this will return the current time stamp.

Comment: Suppose i would like to insert a row means the date field inserted automatically in Unix date time format.

Comment: My table have three field fld_id, fld_date,fld_value. Now i insert the value means the date field automatically inserted in Unix date format.

Comment: @user1804985 Update your table definition and make `fld_date` to use default as `SYSTIMESTAMP`. **If your column `fld_date` is defined as date time then don't worry about the format at time of insertion.** You need to apply the format at the time of retrieval.

Comment: No, I want to insert default Unix date time. Current datetime is '14/03/2010 08:16' means my date field column value like this 1268536560..

Comment: @user1804985 In that case update the default value as `(sysdate - to_date('01-JAN-1970','DD-MON-YYYY')) * (86400)`