# Create trigger for auto incerment id and default unix datetime

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, oracle11g, oracle9i

Any one help me to create a trigger for auto increment fld_id and Unix datetime. My table field is fld_id(int),fld_date(number),fld_value(varchar2).

My insert query is

```
insert into table (fld_value)values('xxx');
insert into table (fld_value)values('yyy');
```

I need the table record like this

```
fld_id    fld_date     fld_value
1         1354357476    xxx
2         1354357478    yyy
```

Please help me to create this.I can't able to do this..

Comment: check this out: [auto increment insert trigger in oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317001/autoincrement-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `fld_id` to be a sequential value, you'll need to create a sequence and a trigger

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 20;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT sequence_name.nextval
    INTO :new.fld_id
    FROM dual;
  :new.fld_date := (SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01') * 60 * 60 * 24;
END;
```